# function to change namefiles of different extention types

Tags: python

I am making in a python script which replaces and add a command at the end of a file. I am using:

```
outfilename=infile.replace(".pdb","-solv"+str(solvcycle)
            + ".pdb")
```

Is it possible to make this function replace `.pdb` or `.xyz` file, or more generally, to replace any extention of the infile? I need the script to replace the name of any infile as it does for `pdb`.

Comment: Maybe make a constant `EXTENSIONS = ['.xyz', '.pdb]` and then put the `outfile` in a loop, such as: `for extension in EXTENSIONS: outile=infile.replace(extension, "-solv"+str(solvcycle) + extension)`

Comment: what is `infile`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it is a `.pdb` or `.xyz` file

Comment: @HernanMiraola Is it a string or a file object?

Comment: It would make your question a lot easier to understand if you added some examples of `infile` and `solvcycle`. Please read about creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

infile = 'foo/bar.xyz'
infile = Path(infile)
new_name = infile.stem + '-solv' + infile.suffix
outfilename = infile.with_name(new_name)
print( str(outfilename) )
# output: foo/bar-solv.xyz
```